# ZFS : how to replace a faulted drive with hotspare

Tags: zfs

I'm new to ZFS and I've one simple and quick question. Here is my zpool :

```
    NAME         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    vmstore      DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz2-0   DEGRADED     0     0     0
        sdd      ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde      ONLINE       0     0     0
        spare-2  DEGRADED     0     0     0
          sdf    FAULTED      5     0     0  too many errors
          sdm    ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdg      ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdh      ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdi      ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdj      ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdk      ONLINE       0     0     0
    logs
      mirror-1   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb1     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb2     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb3     ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      sdm        INUSE     currently in use
```

If I understand correctly, in order to replace my faulted disk (sdf) with my hotspare (sdm), the command would be :

> $ zpool replace vmstore sdf sdm

If someone could confirm, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Please [take the tour](https://serverfault.com/tour) to learn how Server Fault works. Read [how to ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.